# How can you extend a Clojure protocol to another protocol?

Tags: clojure, protocols, abstraction

Suppose I have two protocols:

```
(defprotocol A 
  (f [this]))

(defprotocol B 
  (g [x y]))
```

And I want to extend protocol B to all instances that support protocol A:

```
(extend-protocol A 
  String 
    (f [this] (.length this)))

(extend-protocol B 
  user.A
    (g [x y] (* (f x) (f y))))
```

The primary motivation is to avoid having to extend B separately to all the possible classes that A may be extended to, or even to unknown future classes that other people may extend A to (imagine if A was part of a public API, for example).

However this doesn't work - you get something like the following:

```
(g "abc" "abcd")
=> #<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No implementation of method: :g of protocol: #'user/B found for 
class: java.lang.String>
```

Is this possible at all? If not, is there a sensible workaround to achieve the same objective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that you can implement the function `g` in terms of `f`. If that is the case you have all the polymorphism you need without the protocol `B`.

What I mean is the following, given that `f` is polymorphic, then

```
(defn g [x y]
  (* (f x) (f y)))
```

yields a function `g` which supports all types which implements the protocol `A`.

Often, when protocols are at the very bottom, simple functions defined only in terms of protocol functions (or on other functions which themself use the protocol) makes the whole namespace/library/program very polymorphic, extendable and flexible.

The sequence library is a great example of this. Simplified, there are two polymorphic functions, `first` and `rest`. The rest of the sequence library is ordinary functions.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best approach in my case - the analogy with the sequence library works well here!

Answer (score 10):

Protocols are not types, and do not support inheritance.  A protocol is essentially a named collection of function definitions (and a dispatch mechanism when those functions are called).

If you have multiple types that all happen to have the same implementation, you can simply call a common function.  Alternately, you can create a method map and `extend` each type with that map.  E.g.:

```
(defprotocol P
  (a [p])
  (b [p]))

(deftype R [])
(deftype S [])
(deftype T [])

(def common-P-impl
  {:a (fn [p] :do-a)
   :b (fn [p] :do-b)})

(extend R
  P common-P-impl)
(extend S
  P common-P-impl)
(extend T
  P common-P-impl)
```

If you provide some more detail on your actual scenario, we may be able to suggest the correct approach.

Comment: This would be my solution as well - I think `map` can be leveraged to remove duplication, e.g.
`(map #(extend % P common-P-impl) [R S T])`

Comment: Sorry, `doseq`, or an enclosing `doall` should be used re: map being lazy..

Answer (score 3):

in "Clojure applied" there's a recipe of extending protocol by protocol

```
(extend-protocol TaxedCost
  Object
  (taxed-cost [entity store]
    (if (satisfies? Cost entity)
      (do (extend-protocol TaxedCost
            (class entity)
            (taxed-cost [entity store]
              (* (cost entity store) (+ 1 (tax-rate store))))) 
          (taxed-cost entity store))
      (assert false (str "Unhandled entity: " entity)))))
```

actually nothing prevents you from simply extending protocol by another one

```
(extend-protocol TaxedCost 
  Cost
  (taxed-cost [entity store]
    (* (cost entity store) (+ 1 (tax-rate store)))))
```

while book says it's not possible. I've talked with Alex Miller about this and he said the following:

> It really doesn’t work in all cases. The protocol generates a Java interface and you can for sure, extend a protocol to that interface.
>   The problem is that not every protocol implementation implements that interface - only records or types that do so with an inline declaration like `(defrecord Foo [a] TheProtocol (foo ...))`. If you are implementing a protocol by using `extend-type` or `extend-protocol`, then those instances will NOT be caught by the extension of a protocol interface. So, you really shouldn’t do this :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, protocols can indeed extend protocols.
I made an example here: https://github.com/marctrem/protocol-extend-protocol-example/blob/master/src/extproto/core.clj

In the example, we have an `Animalia` protocol (which allow its members do `dream`) which is extended by a `Erinaceinae` protocol (which allows its members to `go-fast`).

We have a record `Hedgehog` which is part of the `Erinaceinae` protocol. Our instance of the record can both `dream` and `go-fast`.

```
(ns extproto.core
  (:gen-class))


(defprotocol Animalia (dream [this]))

(defprotocol Erinaceinae (go-fast [this]))

(extend-protocol Animalia 
  extproto.core.Erinaceinae
  (dream [this] "I dream about things."))

(defrecord Hedgehog [lovely-name]
  Erinaceinae
  (go-fast [this] (format "%s the Hedgehog has got to go fast." (get this :lovely-name))))



(defn -main
  [& args]  
  (let [my-hedgehog (Hedgehog. "Sanic")]
    (println (go-fast my-hedgehog))
    (println (dream my-hedgehog))))

;1> Sanic the Hedgehog has got to go fast.
;1> I dream about things.
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not completely understand what you are trying to do, I wonder if clojure multimethods would be a better solution for your problem.